# Does a summoned or transformed creature/character fall under animal ruling?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have found this quote (see below), and was wondering if these rules apply to summoned or transformed creature/characters?

> An animal is a living, nonhuman creature, usually a vertebrate with no magical abilities and no innate capacity for language or culture. Animals usually have additional information on how they can serve as companions.

An animal has the following features (unless otherwise noted).

d8 Hit Die.
Base attack bonus equal to 3/4 total Hit Dice (medium progression).
Good Fortitude and Reflex saves.
Skill points equal to 2 + Int modifier (minimum 1) per Hit Die. The following are class skills for animals: Acrobatics, Climb, Fly, Perception, Stealth, and Swim.
Traits: An animal possesses the following traits (unless otherwise noted in a creature's entry).

Intelligence score of 1 or 2 (no creature with an Intelligence score of 3 or higher can be an animal).
Low-light vision.
Alignment: Always neutral.
Treasure: None.
Proficient with its natural weapons only. A noncombative herbivore treats its natural weapons as secondary attacks. Such attacks are made with a –5 penalty on the creature's attack rolls, and the animal receives only 1/2 its Strength modifier as a damage adjustment.
Proficient with no armor unless trained for war. (See FAQs and Handle Animal Skill.)
Animals breathe, eat, and sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules apply to any creature with the "animal" type.

"Animals" are a specific subset of creatures that have the animal type. How do you know what an animal is? Look it up in the bestiary and see if it has the "Animal" type. See the [black bear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/bear/black-bear) entry on d20pfsrd.com for an example.

To answer your question more directly:

1. These rules apply to summoned creatures, if the creatures are animals.
2. These rules apply to creatures that have been somehow transformed, if the creature is an animal.
3. These rules generally do not apply to characters, because they are not animals.

All things considered, you won't have to worry much about it.  All the stat blocks already have these mechanics built in.  If you summon a wolf, you just use the stat block for wolves in the bestiary - no modifications needed.

Comment: So this only occurs in gm created animals?

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where a player would create an animal.

Comment: Was just curious as i came across it. Wasn't sure (even though it states unless otherwise noted) i mean if i summon a wolf I don't want it to really lose that much stats. Thanks

Comment: If you summon a creature, you don't lose anything, since you are not the summoned creature. If you shapeshift into a creature, the spell/effect explains what you get from the creature and what not. You might lose stuff, if you use the wrong spell/form. Don't Baleful Polymorph yourself.